# How to insert a table in ms excel using apache java poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, jexcelapi

I am trying to insert a table in Excel using Java Apache Poi. But when I am opening the xlsx file it is throwing the following error and I could not solve it:

```
Removed Part: /xl/tables/table1.xml part with XML error. (Table) Load error. Line 2
repaired records: table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (table)
```

My code is the following:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTable;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumns;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableStyleInfo;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Architecture");

    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();


    cttable.setDisplayName("Table1");
    cttable.setId(1);
    cttable.setName("Test");
    cttable.setRef("A1:C11");
    cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);

    CTTableStyleInfo styleInfo = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
    styleInfo.setShowColumnStripes(false);
    styleInfo.setShowRowStripes(true);


    CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
    columns.setCount(3);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
      column.setId(i);
      column.setName("Column" + i);
    }

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Office\\TimeSheet\\JavaBooks.xlsx")) {
      workbook.write(outputStream);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I insert a table in Microsft Excel using Apache Java Poi?

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: i am Using latest apache poi 3.17.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There must be at least content in sheet cells for table column names. In your case cells `A1:C1` in sheet `Architecture` must have content. In former versions of  `apache poi` this content had must match the table column names. In current version now the setting the cell content updates the table column names.

Your code extended to work:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTable;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumns;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableStyleInfo;

public class ExcelTableTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Architecture");

    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
    //XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable(null); //since apache poi 4.0.0
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

    cttable.setDisplayName("Table1");
    cttable.setId(1);
    cttable.setName("Test");
    cttable.setRef("A1:C11");
    cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);

    CTTableStyleInfo styleInfo = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
    styleInfo.setName("TableStyleMedium2");
    styleInfo.setShowColumnStripes(false);
    styleInfo.setShowRowStripes(true);

    CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
    columns.setCount(3);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
      column.setId(i);
      column.setName("Column" + i);
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
      XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
      for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
        if(r == 0) { //first row is for column headers
          cell.setCellValue("Column"+ (c+1)); //content **must** be here for table column names
        } else {
          //cell.setCellValue("Data R"+ (r+1) + "C" + (c+1));
        }
      }
    }    

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("ExcelTableTest.xlsx")) {
      workbook.write(outputStream);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this be done in legacy HSSF workbooks? I haven't been able to find a way :(

Comment: @MattWeiler: Not possible using `apache poi` until now. There is only `XSSFTable` which implements [Table](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Table.html). There is no `HSSFTable` until now.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
Is that to say that **apache poi** doesn't support it or the `.xls` format doesn't support it? 
When I use **Excel** and insert a table to wrap data, and save it as `.xls` format, it looks the same as if I use the `.xlsx` format.
Does this mean that the `.xls` format supports tables or does **Excel** just apply styles to the cells/rows to make them look like tables in the `.xlsx` format?

Comment: @MattWeiler: The binary `*.xls` `BIFF` format supports table aka ListObject too. But `apache poi` does not provide any classes to handle them until now.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. 
So I guess I'll just have to apply cell/row styles if the user opts to have `.xls` files generated and apply a proper `table` if the user opts to have `.xlsx` files generated.

Answer (score 3):

in case of excel errors appears with file opening.... Remove part:t /xl/tables/table1.xml with XML error.

seemed to be caused by duplicite table/tableColumn section in table1.xml

can be fixed with slightly different column name creations/setting

```
       for (int i = 0; i <= REPORT_COL_COUNT; i++) {
           String colName = sh.getRow(FIRST_DATA_ROW-1).getCell(i).getStringCellValue();
           CTTableColumn column = columns.getTableColumnArray(i);
           column.setName(colName);
       }
```

tested with poi 5.2.2

Comment: can you write full example, because I tried what I have written, but it doens't help

Answer (score 0):

Additional to 'Axel Richter' I had to add the Autofilter. I realized when I opened the Excel with an ZipArchiv-software.

Here is the code I use:

```
private void createCTTable(XSSFTable table)
{
   cttable = table.getCTTable();
   cttable.setDisplayName("Tabelle1");
   cttable.setId(1);
   cttable.setName("Test");
   cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);
   AreaReference my_data_range = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0),
         new CellReference(rowVectors.size(), header.length - 1), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
   cttable.setRef(my_data_range.formatAsString());
   CTAutoFilter autofilter = cttable.addNewAutoFilter();
   autofilter.setRef(my_data_range.formatAsString());
}
```

'header' is an Array with Strings and rowVectors is an Collection of Objects with the values of the DataBody of the table.

I use Apache Poi 4.1.1 .